# JavaScript style, how to apply two classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's i describe my problem:

I have a React component like below

```
import React from 'react';

class Question extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <div className="view fourth-effect">  
      <a 
        href={this.props.link} 
        title="Full Image">
          <img src={this.props.image}/>
      </a>  
      <div className="mask"></div>  
      <span className='title'>{this.props.title}</span>
      <span className='owner'>{this.props.owner}</span>
    </div> 
  }
}

Question.propTypes = {
  title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  owner: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  image: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  link : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

Question.defaultProps = {
  title: 'none',
  owner: '-',
  image: '-',
  link : '-'
};

export default Question
```

For styling i'm using css file. And now i'm interesting to use inline style with React, but i've stuck...

How i can apply two classes for an React element like i do in css

```
<div className="view fourth-effect">
```

just using JS object it should be something like this...

```
<div style={Style.question}> /*JS style object*/
```

How to combine two classes using inline style in React?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you would be instrested in [Radium](http://projects.formidablelabs.com/radium/). It allows to use `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active` pseudo-selectors, also it automatically adds vendor prefixes

Comment: @imkost, Thanks i've heard about Radium, but for now i would like to summarize my knowledge around React and JS Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style attribute also accepts an array. So you can do:

`<div style={[Style.question, Style.new]}>`